# jHipster microservice Swagger-UI not available in registry / control center API tab

Tags: microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry, jhipster-gateway

Microservice local project based on jHipster 7.8.1

Generated:

- registry
- control center
- API Gateway
- test microservice

Test microservice has classs with @RestController @RequestMapping("/api") @GetMapping("/cars") annotations.

Authorization with JWT Token. Base64-secret was updated, same value in every app.
I can see my test app and api gateway in control center and registry, but they are not visible in API tab.

I would like to see my test microservice app swagger visible via registry/control center API tab. What should i do to achieve that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it's related to replacement springfox to springdoc - https://www.jhipster.tech/2022/01/02/jhipster-release-7.5.0.html. It looks that control-center hasn't been applied to this change.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31927757)